# Adding "0" decimal in a donut chart using ggplot2 from R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, donut-chart

I have created a donut chart in R using ggplot2 package. Now I need to add "0" decimal in the "No" slice. It is now shown in the graph as "74%" - but I want to present this as "74.0%". The followings are the codes and the graph -

```
df = data.frame(Dep = c("No", 
                               "Mild",
                               "Moderate",
                               "Moderately Severe",
                               "Severe"),
                Percentage = c(74.0, 12.8, 9.4, 2.3, 1.6),
                Count = c(284, 49, 36, 9, 6))


df$Dep = factor(df$Dep, levels = c("No", 
                                                 "Mild",
                                                 "Moderate",
                                                 "Moderately Severe",
                                                 "Severe"))

df = df %>%
    arrange(desc(Dep)) %>%
    mutate (Percentage) %>%
    mutate (ypos = cumsum(Percentage)-0.5*Percentage)

donut= ggplot(df, aes(x =2, y=Percentage,fill=Dep))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    coord_polar("y", start=180)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")+
    theme_void()+
    geom_text(aes(y=ypos, label=paste0(round(Percentage,1),"%")),
              color = "black", size=4.5, angle = 0)+
    xlim(0.25, 2.5)+theme(legend.position=c(.5, .5))+
    theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold",)) +
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))

donut
```

I got this donut chart -
[image]

I am searching for this solution but cannot be able to find anything useful. Thanks in advance. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Change `round(Percentage,1)` to `sprintf("%.1f", Percentage)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `sprintf()`. Please find below a reprex.

**Reprex**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'dplyr'
#> Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df = data.frame(Depression = c("No", 
                               "Mild",
                               "Moderate",
                               "Moderately Severe",
                               "Severe"),
                Percentage = c(74.0, 12.8, 9.4, 2.3, 1.6),
                Count = c(284, 49, 36, 9, 6))


df$Depression = factor(df$Depression, levels = c("No", 
                                                 "Mild",
                                                 "Moderate",
                                                 "Moderately Severe",
                                                 "Severe"))

df = df %>%
  arrange(desc(Depression)) %>%
  mutate (Percentage) %>%
  mutate (ypos = cumsum(Percentage)-0.5*Percentage)

donut= ggplot(df, aes(x =2, y=Percentage,fill=Depression))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  coord_polar("y", start=180)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2")+
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(y=ypos, label=paste0(sprintf("%.1f",Percentage),"%")),
            color = "black", size=4.5, angle = 0)+
  xlim(0.25, 2.5)+theme(legend.position=c(.5, .5))+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold",)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))

donut
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: FYI it’s not necessary to use `round` with `sprintf` here, just `sprintf` is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to format your percentages using `scales::percent`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 2, y = Percentage, fill = Dep)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 180) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = scales::percent(Percentage, scale = 1, accuracy = .1)),
    color = "black", size = 4.5, angle = 0
  ) +
  xlim(0.25, 2.5) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.5, .5)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", )) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))
```

[image]