# How to retain precision of number on data labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating plots in ggplot, I want all of my data labels rounded to two decimal places. However, when there is a trailing zero (e.g., 2.80), the data label only displays "2.8." I have tried unsuccessfully to modify my code to fix this in many various ways. I also ensured that the data in the data frame are rounded to two decimal places. Nothing fixes it. Can anyone help? Pasting current syntax and link to plot below:

```
resultsCS20182gg<-ggplot(CS20182, aes(x=Status, y=Mean, ymin=LL, ymax=UL), number_format(accuracy =.2))
CS20182plot<-resultsCS20182gg+  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LL, ymax=UL, color=Status), width=.1, cex=.6)+
  scale_color_grey(start=0.7, end=0.11, breaks=c("Food Insecure", "Food Secure"), labels=c("Food Insecure", "Food Secure"))+
  geom_point(size=6, shape=18)+
  geom_label(aes(label=Mean), nudge_y= 0.1, size=4, label.size = NA)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2.50,3), breaks=seq(2.50,3,.05))+guides(y=guide_axis(n.dodge=1), check.overlap=T)+xlab("")+
  theme_apa()+
  ylab("IE Mean -/+ SE")+
  labs(title="IE Marginal Means in Emerging Adulthood")+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill=NA, size=1)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, face="bold")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, face="bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color="black")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
  guides(col = guide_legend(reverse = FALSE), shape = guide_legend(reverse = FALSE)) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, color="black")) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(family="sans", face="bold", size=14, color="black", hjust = 0.5))
CS20182plot
```

[image: plot]

Data set is:

[image: dataset picture]

Comment: Can you post the `CS20182` data set, or a representative substitute? Difficult to help without it.

Comment: Try with `geom_label(aes(label=scales::number(Mean, accuracy = .01)), ...)`. Related post: [Adding "0" decimal in a donut chart using ggplot2 from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71364833/adding-0-decimal-in-a-donut-chart-using-ggplot2-from-r/71364936#71364936)

Comment: oh my gosh, @stefan that worked. Thank you!